# parsing nested JSON statement with arrays in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I looked around but could not find an answer addressing my issue. I am new to coding and use this example to get into the subject matter.
I want to parse a nested JSON statement, the code I am using to test out is the following:

```
import Foundation

let jsonDict = """
{"Data":[{"id": 40, "val": 600,"valStr": "600","sysVal": "580","inst": 0,"valid": "true"},
{"id": 44, "val": 600,"valStr": "600","sysVal": "580","inst": 0,"valid": "true"}]}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
print("IF statement ")


let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonDict, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any],
    let data = dictionary["Data"]
{
    print("Data= \(data)")
}
```

I can access the overall content of the root element but not the elements within the array. I would be really happy for any help here.

Comment: Your `data` variable is an array of dictionary. Go from there. There are countless examples of iterating arrays and accessing values from dictionaries. Please clarify what issue you are having accessing elements of the array.

Comment: BTW - change `as!` to `as?`.

Answer (score 1):

Drop `JSONSerialization` and use `Decodable`. It's more descriptive and more efficient.

`result` is the `Root` struct representing the outer dictionary. The dictionary keys become the struct members.

```
let jsonString = """
{"Data":[{"id": 40, "val": 600,"valStr": "600","sysVal": "580","inst": 0,"valid": "true"},
{"id": 44, "val": 600,"valStr": "600","sysVal": "580","inst": 0,"valid": "true"}]}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case data = "Data"}

    let data : [Subject]
}

struct Subject : Decodable {
    let id, val, inst : Int
    let valStr, sysVal, valid : String
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for item in result.data {
        print(item.id, item.val, item.valid)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Dear Vadian, dear rmaddy

many thanks for the help. It works and brought me forward closer to my solution!

I guess I have still a long way to go, many thanks again.

Robert